# How to call another api inside an api in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

I want when admin added score to some user in my next app, it updates the DB and notify user. Getting old score from DB and adding new score to it and store it on DB works good. But `await notifyUserByPhone()` makes a catch with empty error.

My /api/admin/score/give-as-gift code:

```js
            if (/* some checks */) {

              //calculating new score
              const currect_score = currentScore[0].score;
              const new_score = parseInt(score) + parseInt(currect_score);
              const addScore = await query(
                `
              UPDATE users SET score = ? WHERE phone = ?
              `,
                [new_score, phone]
              );
              const notify = await notifyUserByPhone(
                phone,
                `Congratz! ${score} added to you!`
              );
              console.log(notify);//nothing

              //other working codes
              return res.status(200).json({
                status: "success",
              });
            } else {
              return res.status(500).json({
                ...
              });
            }
```

`notifyUserByPhone` code which is located in `/utils/notifications.js` in root folder:

```
export async function notifyUserByPhone(phone, message) {
  const notify = await fetch("/api/notifications/notify-by-phone", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ phone, message }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await notify.json();

  return data;
}
```

I even tried content of `notifyUserByPhone` directly in my api content. But same result happens.

Remember I dont want to use content of `/api/notifications/notify-by-phone` in my score api. Because i have to call notify api many times in the app and i want to call just one function and not a big block of code.

Comment: That's not something you can do. You cannot call a route handler as a function in NextJS.